# Question in proving almost universal

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

In Jech's third millennium, theorem 13.9 states that transitive class $M$ is an inner model of $ZF$ if and only if it is closed under Godel operations and is almost universal. The proof of first part includes the following.

> If $X$ is a subset of an inner model $M$,
>   then $X ⊂ V_α ∩ M$ for some $α$, and $V_α ∩ M\in M$ because $α ∈ M$ and
>   $V_α ∩M = V^M_α$.

I think the proof is problematic because if $X$ contains all ordinals (it is possible since $M$ does), then there is no $\alpha$ that $X ⊂ V_α ∩ M$ for some $α$, and $V_α ∩ M\in M$.

Comment: For future reference, please don't delete your questions after they receive answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Also, in this case, unlike many other self-deletions, I can't really see anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that it says $X$ is a sub**set** of $M$.  That means $X$ is a set, not just a class, so it cannot contain all the ordinals, and is contained in some $V_\alpha$ since every set is contained in some $V_\alpha$.